# Use IVS Real-Time Broadcast SDK in a Node.js environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-ivs

I'm using [Amazon IVS real-time streaming](https://aws.amazon.com/ivs/features/real-time-streaming/) and I would like server-side code (Lambda or EC2) to join a stage as a participant so that it can stream pre-recorded audio, and process individual participant's streams server-side.

Is there a way to do this?

The [IVS real-time streaming Web broadcast SDK](https://aws.github.io/amazon-ivs-web-broadcast/docs/real-time-sdk-guides/introduction) is browser-only and doesn't work in a Node.js environment.

I've read about [Server-Side Composition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ivs/latest/RealTimeUserGuide/server-side-composition.html) but this appears to mix audio and video from all stage participants and then sends this mixed video to an IVS channel. I want to process participant's streams individually server-side. Server-Side Composition also appears to send video to an IVS channel, and my participant streams will be audio only.

Perhaps there's a completely different solution that would be easier? I'm trying to create a real-time audio chatbot similar to ChatGPT. The steps I'm trying to reproduce are as follows:

1. Stream audio from a browser to a server
2. Transcribe audio
3. Send transcription to an LLM
4. Convert the response to audio
5. Stream the audio back to the browser

To be honest the difficult part seems to be the first step (real-time streaming from browser to server), which is why I started looking at WebRTC and then AWS IVS real-time streaming. I'd rather not have to create my own WebRTC and Websockets servers and wire everything up manually.

Comment: Your best bet is to use something like Pion (https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ivs-stage-recorder/) to record the stream and pass audio clips to the transcription process - or GStreamer to do something similar (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/webrtchttp/whipsink.html?gi-language=c).